# 2 templates authentication.tpl different

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I currently customize a prestashop site. I have 2 different connection URLs and I would like to have 1 different style between these 2 urls in my template authentication.tpl because 1 url will be for customers of the "customer" group and the other url will be for the group "Enterprise" . Do you have any idea how I could do that.
 
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/319134-setting-different-css-for-each-shop-of-a-multistore-site/

Comment: No, nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try width override AuthController.php and in your connexion link add in url &spe=1

```
class AuthController extends AuthControllerCore
{   
      public function initContent()
      {
           Parent::initContent();

           if (Tools::getValue('spe')) {            
               $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'authentication2.tpl');
           }
      }
}
```

Regards